# jQuery.getScript doesn't load after a page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, getscript

I am trying to debug some code which loads a script with jQuery like this

```
$.getScript('src/myscript.js', function(){ // start page });
```

The majority of the time, everything works fine. But some users report intermittent problems with the page not starting. Based on logs I have added to the code, it is clear that for some users, the load callback is never triggered again after they load the page a second time. Clearing their cache removes the problem, but every subsequent reload of the page...it stops again. Other users report intermittent problems, same log results. The user who always has the problem is using Chrome on a Mac.

Anyone had problems like this? I can't find anything in the docs or Googling which would suggest a possible reason..

Comment: By default, `$.getScript()` doesn't use cached version of loaded script so are you sure you don't force it in some way? Anyway, even for cached script, the success callback is fired

Comment: @AWolff...Thanks. I've checked all code to see if $.ajaxSetup has been used to force cache...but nothing. It works all the time for most users. Just some users reporting the problem.

Comment: These users should have some error in their network browser panel because this is the only reason the success callback wouldn't be fired AFAIK. It could be a browser specific behaviour though

Comment: @AWolff..thanks. The users don't get anything in the network panel in Chrome. It just doesn't even seem to trigger the load.

Comment: Are you calling it from other event, as e.g inside document ready event or window load event or any other nested event? There was change in lastest jquery branch 3.x that could explain some part of code won't be called. So are you sure `$.getScript()` is called? Not just the success callback but the function itself

Comment: BTW, which jq version are you using? Same behaviour with older/newer version? I know, this kind of 'inconsistent' bug is hard to debug, so good luck.

Comment: Using latest version. Didn't have any luck with this. Ended up putting the scripts into the html header and not loading them programmatically. Solved the problem, but obviously they don't load in background now.